# In comma delimited string is it possible to say "exists" in php

Tags: php, string

In a comma delimited string, in php, as such: `"1,2,3,4,4,4,5"` is it possible to say:

```
if(!/*4 is in string bla*/){
   // add it via the .=
}else{
  // do something
}
```

In arrays you can do in_array(); but this isn't a set of arrays and I don't want to have to convert it to an array ....

Comment: If you want to do item checks, you'd probably be better off storing it natively as an array and only converting to string when you need it as a string.

Comment: could use a regular expression. it would be an easy `preg_match()`

Comment: You can do some string matching.. but really, `explode`-ing & just making it an array will save you a lot of grief in the long run.

Comment: Use this: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try exploding it into an array before searching:

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,4,4,5";
$exploded = explode(",", $str);

if(in_array($number, $exploded)){
    echo 'In array!';
}
```

You can also replace numbers and modify the array before "sticking it back together" with implode:

```
$strAgain = implode(",", $exploded);
```

Comment: "I don't want to have to convert it to an array"

Comment: Then he's turning something simple into something that is needlessly complex. Introducing regexes instead of simply exploding the string is just madness.

Comment: posters often say they don't want to do X with out understanding the issue, so often X is the right approach

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this with regex:

```
$re = '/(^|,)' + preg_quote($your_number) + '(,|$)/';
if(preg_match($re, $your_string)) {
    // ...
}
```

But that's not exactly the clearest of code; someone else (or even yourself, months later) who had to maintain the code would probably not appreciate having something that's hard to follow. Having it actually be an array would be clearer and more maintainable:

```
$values = explode(',', $your_string);
if(in_array((str)$number, $values)) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need to turn the array into a string again, you can always use `implode()`:

```
$new_string = implode(',', $values);
```